# JSHint "Expected an operator but instead saw 'yield'" error for generator function steps

Tags: javascript, node.js, atom-editor, jshint

I have a generator function that calls two async tasks that do not return results:

```
co(function *(){
    const targetPath = `${appPaths.environmentBuildDirectory}/${program.environment}`
    yield directoryContainsRequiredAEMFiles(targetPath)
    yield openJarFile(`${targetPath}/aem-${program.environment}-*.jar`)
    console.log(chalk.green(`AEM ${program.environment} enviornment starting up...`))
})
.catch(error => {throw new Error(chalk.red(error))})
```

Neither of the above yield statements need to return anything, they're just tasks that need to be done. Additionally, since this generator function is based on promises I don't need to evaluate the result of the async call b/c if it failed or was rejected, it's handled by the `.catch` function.

This works perfectly fine, but JSHint does not like it:

[image: jshint error]

I've been reading through the docs for jshint and I can't figure out how to turn this error off. I know I can get rid of it by declaring variables to catch the result of each yield statement, but I think adding that to the code just to make JSHint happy is a mistake.

Is there a setting for this? At the moment my `.jshintrc` contains:

```
{
    "asi":true,
    "esversion": 6
}
```

Note that even though you see the semicolon error in the screen shot which may lead you to think the .jshintrc isn't being recognized it's a weird error. The missing semicolons are indeed being ignored by the linter (e.g. line 22), I just still get the error message in the hover for other lines. Regardless, it's not important to the above question, I'm just trying to head off answers and comments saying that .jshintrc isn't being recognized/is misconfigured.

Comment: You still need to put a semicolon on the previous line to get rid of the yield warning.

Comment: What's the reason behind it? Shouldn't the semicolon be inserted via asi? When the javascript is being validated? Wouldn't that semicolon add be just to make jshint happy? (not trying to be confrontational, just trying to understand).

Comment: May I suggest ESLint in Atom, I just copy and pasted you code into my Atom and no lint errors.

Comment: Oh man thank you @Keith! I replaced jshint with eslint, configured eslint, and now I'm good to go. Thanks!